# iOS Swift Floating Action Button Moves When Changing Screens

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am having some trouble with my Floating Action Button in Swift. I am using Floaty found here: [`https://github.com/kciter/Floaty`](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty). So it works well on the first time I click the "Calls" screen, but when I switch to another tab, it goes behind the tab bar. The code I use to set up the FAB can be found below.

What I think is going on is that whenever the tabs are switched, the view alternates between recognizing the tabBar and Safe Inset Areas, but sometimes it doesn't and only the paddingX and paddingY values I supplied in the beginning are supported.

I have tried switching between a TableViewController and a ViewController with a tableView in it, but that doesn't really seem to be the problem. I have also tried resetting the padding on every viewWillAppear() just to make sure it is at the right height, but that did not work either. Lastly, I tried to add constraints to the FAB. That was a complex process, that I don't think I did correctly, so it didn't end up working either. The code I used can be seen below.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening, or what I can do to make it work? Right now, my other option is to either get rid of the FAB entirely, or switch to some other library like Google's Material Design Components and use that FAB.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Floaty
import Material

class CallCreationViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let floaty : Floaty = Floaty()

    var connections: [User] = []
    var filteredConnections : [User] = []
    var selectedIds: [String] = []

    let inset : CGFloat = 34
    let blue : Color = Color(red:0.09, green:0.04, blue:0.35, alpha:1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        floaty.buttonColor = blue
        floaty.plusColor = .white

        let voiceItem : FloatyItem = FloatyItem()
        voiceItem.title = "Start Voice Call"
        voiceItem.icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "baseline_phone_white_24pt")
        voiceItem.iconTintColor = .white
        voiceItem.buttonColor = blue
        voiceItem.handler = { item in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startVoiceCall", sender: self)
            self.floaty.close()
        }

        let videoItem : FloatyItem = FloatyItem()
        videoItem.title = "Start Video Call"
        videoItem.icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "baseline_video_call_white_24pt")
        videoItem.iconTintColor = .white
        videoItem.buttonColor = blue
        videoItem.handler = { item in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startVideoCall", sender: self)
            self.floaty.close()
        }

        let broadcastItem : FloatyItem = FloatyItem()
        broadcastItem.title = "Start Broadcast"
        broadcastItem.icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "baseline_settings_input_antenna_white_24pt")
        broadcastItem.iconTintColor = .white
        broadcastItem.buttonColor = blue
        broadcastItem.handler = { item in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startBroadcast", sender: self)
            self.floaty.close()
        }

        floaty.addItem(item: voiceItem)
        floaty.addItem(item: videoItem)
        floaty.addItem(item: broadcastItem)

        floaty.respondsToKeyboard = false
        //let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: floaty, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self.tabBarController?.tabBar, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

        floaty.sticky = true
        floaty.paddingX = inset
        floaty.paddingY = inset
        self.view.addSubview(floaty)

        //let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: floaty, attribute: .bottomMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.navigationController?.navigationBar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

        //floaty.addConstraint(constraint)

        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not familiar with Floaty, my guess would be that it's your tableview being underneath the tab bar that's causing it to fluctuate in it's location.

For example if I added a generic UIView like this:

```
    let greenView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.addSubview(greenView)
```

It would be underneath the tab bar.

If you're looking for a quick fix, and don't necessarily need your tableview to extend behind your tab bar, you should just be able to add this line:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout.remove(UIRectEdge.bottom)
```

before setting up the Floaty in viewDidLoad and your tableview won't extend below the bottom tab bar.